# Send Headers to a Redirect URL in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension, which will redirect a URL to another URL, and send an extra header along with the Redirected URL.

There are two approaches to send headers as per the documentation.

1. chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest
2. chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders

I used the second approach. The issue is that I am able to get headers in the preflight call, but not in the second call after preflight.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
            const headers = "My Value;
            if (headers !== "") {
                details.requestHeaders.push({
                    name: "New Header",
                    value: headers,
                });
            }
        return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders}
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders", "extraHeaders"]
);
```

I am getting headers in the preflight call, but I want it in the second call.

I also tried it in the `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` but no luck.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function (request) {
        const url = "https://newurl.com/";
        const headers = []
        headers.push({
            name: "MyHeader",
            value: "MyValue",
        })
        return {
            redirectUrl: url,
            requestHeaders: headers
        };
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["blocking", "extraHeaders"]
);
```

Comment: I am checking for request headers and not the response headers @wOxxOm

Comment: I see. Maybe it's just not implemented. Try reporting in https://crbug.com.